# How to iterate json file with index and render with react native component?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have a JSON file like this :

```
{
  "type": {
    "1": {
      "book_name": "Lorem ipsum",
    },
   "2": {
     "book_name": "Lorem ipsum",
   }
}
```

I need to iterate each name of this json file.

In my project I import the local json file like this :

```
import books from '../data/books.json';
```

To access each name, I can do for example :

```
const names = books.type;
<Text>{names[1].book_name}</Text>
```

I'm trying to render my datas into the view with the `map function` but I don't understand how to use it in my case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your values in a array and you can use it in map

You can do something like this:

```
const books  = {"type":{
    "1":{
        "book_name":"Lorem ipsum",
    },
    "2":{
        "book_name":"Lorem ipsum",
    },
    "3":{
        "book_name":"Lorem ipsum",
    }
}}

    const array = [];

    Object.entries(books).map(([key, value]) => {
        Object.entries(value).map(([key, value]) => {
            Object.entries(value).map(([key, value]) => {
                array.push(value);
            })

        })
    })


  return(
    <View style={{flex:1,alignItems:"center",justifyContent:"center"}}>
  {array.map((item, key) => 
        {
            return(
            <View>
              <Text> {item} </Text>
            </View>
          )
        })}
      </View>
  );
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values(obj)` but the best approach is type property been an array of objects.

```js
{
  "type": [{  "book_name": "Lorem ipsum"}, {"book_name": "Lorem ipsum"}]
}
```

Comment: Hi Diego Oliveira, I can't reformat my json file. Too big ! 
I need to iterate this json file to avoid the manual writing